# multiple joins in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making a mock twitter website, and for the main feed, i'm trying to query my database for all posts, and reposts from the users that someone follows where $user_id is the person currently logged in.  But it is only showing the reposted posts when i run the query.  Can anyone please give me suggestions on how to fix this problem?

```
$query_feed = "SELECT posts.post, posts.date, users.handle, posts.id, posts.image,        users.profile_pic, repost.post_id, repost.user_id
                FROM posts
                JOIN users ON posts.author_id = users.id
                JOIN following ON " . $user_id . " = following.follower_id
                JOIN repost ON posts.id = repost.post_id
                WHERE (posts.author_id = following.followee_id) OR (repost.user_id = following.followee_id)
                ORDER BY posts.id desc";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have an "inner join" on repost ("join" is really short for "inner join"):

`JOIN repost ON posts.id = repost.post_id`

Doing this means that you will only ever get a record in your result set if there is a matching record in `repost`

Instead try an "outer join" or "left join"

`LEFT JOIN repost ON posts.id = repost.post_id`

This should mean that you get records even if there is nothing in `repost`

I have simplified your tables a little (removed columns), but proven the point with a SqlFiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee33a

Comment: I tried OUTER JOIN, and it gives me a syntax error in my SQL query.  and left join didn't affect the output of my query at all.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to a SqlFiddle that proves the SQL works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee33a

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `repost` table to eliminate records in the result set, you'll need to use an outer join.

Also, your `join` condition for the `following` table is in the `where` clause, and the `where` clause contains your `join` condition.  Additionally, since your `join` condition for `following` references a field in `repost`, the join order is incorrect.

```
$query_feed = "SELECT posts.post, posts.date, users.handle, posts.id, posts.image,        users.profile_pic, repost.post_id, repost.user_id
                FROM posts
                JOIN users ON posts.author_id = users.id
                LEFT JOIN repost ON posts.id = repost.post_id
                JOIN following ON (posts.author_id = following.followee_id) OR (repost.user_id = following.followee_id)
                WHERE " . $user_id . " = following.follower_id
                ORDER BY posts.id desc";
```

I'm not sure how MySQL handles things exactly, but you may still have problems with `NULL`s from the `LEFT JOIN` when you do the `following` table join.  I'd run the query in a Query Analyzer to determine if you're getting expected results.